# Настройки lineChart в PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

Код создания линейной диаграммы:

```
    $plotArea = new PlotArea(
        (new Layout())->setShowVal(true), 
        [
            new DataSeries(
                'lineChart', 
                null, 
                range(0, count($values) - 1), 
                [], 
                ['cat1', 'cat2', 'cat3', 'cat4'], 
                [5, 2, 4, 6]
            )
        ]
    );

    $chart = new Chart(
        'lineChart',
        new Title('Chat title'),
        null,
        $plotArea,
        true,
        DataSeries::EMPTY_AS_GAP,
        new Title('xLabel'),
        new Title('yLabel')
    );
```

Все бы хорошо, но подписи осей по Х и Y очень крупные, а также значения точек на графике находятся на линии графика.

Как изменить размер шрифта подписей?

Как установить позицию значений на графике как в Excel - "вверху"?

Comment: Почитать документацию к `PhpSpreadsheet` не пробовали? Там куча примеров. Ну и поиск по самому `stackoverflow` тоже никто пока не отменял :)

Comment: @phpBear а Вы думаете я бы спрашивал тут, если бы были ответы в документации?